# Blue Screen of Death 0x000007b

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I am getting a blue screen of death as I try to boot into Windows 7. The BSOD error code is:
STOP 0x000007b

System specs:
Intel i5
ATI Radeon 7750 HD
Windows 7 Home Premium

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Advanced troubleshooting for "[Stop error code 0x0000007B (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103)" errors in Windows XP is probably what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

**Bug Check 0x7B: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE bug check has a value of 0x0000007B. This bug check 
>   indicates that the Microsoft Windows operating system has lost access
>   to the system partition during startup.

Which HDD do you use? Have you changed the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI? If yes, check this:

**Error message occurs after you change the SATA mode of the boot drive**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976